# Resize image in PHP from blob in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, gd

I have a large image I want to resize while keeping the proportions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   $blob = mysql_fetch_...();

   $gd = imagecreatefromstring($blob);
   $resized = imagecreatetruecolor(X, Y); // new image dimensions
   imagecopyresampled(....);

   ob_start();
   imagejpeg($resized);
   $new_blob = ob_get_clean();

   mysql_query(... update table ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are innumerable image resize scripts out there (google keywords: php thumbnailer). Alternatively roll your own using GD. Load the blob into a string, and use the imagecreatefromstring() function to create the image.